# Trouble setting a variable with class scope from the constructor - Java, MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, variables, constructor, scope

I'm trying to set a variable with class scope with a constructor, whenever I print out from within the constructor the variable is set to the correct value but whenever I try to use that variable in another method within the same class the value is null. How do I use the firstNameTest variable outside of the constructor correctly?

This is the constructor and calling method:

```
public class Member extends javax.swing.JFrame {



DefaultTableModel rentalsTableModel;
String customerID;
String firstNameTest; //Variable declared with class scope.


public Member() {

    initComponents();
    rentalsTableModel = (DefaultTableModel)tblRentals.getModel();
}

Member(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String email, String over18, String dateJoined, String dateExpired, String fines) throws SQLException {

    System.out.println(firstName); // Successfully prints value.
    firstNameTest = firstName;
    System.out.println(firstNameTest); // Successfully prints value.
}

...                                       

private void btnChangeCustomerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

    customerID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Customer ID.");

    MemberDAO member = new MemberDAO();
    try {

        List membersDetails = member.getMembersDetails(customerID);
        System.out.println(firstNameTest); // Value is null.
        txtFullName.setText(firstNameTest);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        System.err.println(ex);
        System.out.println("Failed to get Details.");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to retrieve data.");
    }
}
```

Called Method:

```
public List<Member> getMembersDetails(String ID) throws SQLException{

    List<Member> membersDetails = new ArrayList();

    String getMembershipDetails = "SELECT first_name, last_name, phone_number, email, over_18, date_joined, date_expire, fines FROM members"
            + " WHERE member_id = " + ID + ";";

    try {
        DBConnection mc = new DBConnection();
        dbConnection = mc.getConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(getMembershipDetails);

        while(rs.next()){
            String firstName = rs.getString("first_name");
            String lastName = rs.getString("last_name");
            String phoneNumber = rs.getString("phone_number");
            String email = rs.getString("email");
            String over18 = rs.getString("over_18");
            String dateJoined = rs.getString("date_joined");
            String dateExpired = rs.getString("date_expire");
            String fines = rs.getString("fines");

            System.out.println(firstName);
            System.out.println(dateExpired);

            Member m;
            m = new Member(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, email, over18, dateJoined, dateExpired, fines);
            membersDetails.add(m);

            System.out.println(membersDetails.get(0));
        }    

    }  catch (SQLException ex){
        System.err.println(ex);
        System.out.println("Failed to get Membership Details.");
        return null;
    } finally{
        if (ps != null){
            ps.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null){
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    } return membersDetails;
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here, but only some parts of it are relevant  -why would you need so many properties to demonstrate the problem? Why do you need a database to demonstrate the problem? Additionally, you haven't really shown what the code you've written does. It's hard to help you without a short but complete program demonstrating the issue clearly.

Comment: This appears to be missing some important code. You have two constructors, a public no-arg and a package with arguments, but the constructor with arguments neither chains nor calls stuff like `initComponents()`.

Comment: Where do you get null ?

Comment: I apologise for all the code, I have problem filtering and editing it. Ninad i get null in btnChangeCustomerActionPerformed(... at this line : System.out.println(firstNameTest); // Value is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line -

```
System.out.println(firstNameTest); // Value is null.
```

to

```
System.out.println(((Member)membersDetails.get(0)).firstNameTest); // Value is null.
```

Comment: Ty for the suggestion but when I tried this the IDE says it cannot find symbol, any ideas?

Comment: Which symbol is not found - membersDetails?

Comment: firstNameTest after get(0).